# How to use ViewModels in Edit Action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, view, visual-studio-2012, ef-code-first

I would like to get into the habit of using `ViewModels`.
In the past I have only used them in my `Create Actions` and I never figured how to use them in `Edit Actions`. I used `Domain Entities` instead.

Let's say I have the following:

Using `Entity Framework Code First`

**POCO class** in Domain project

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }        

    public string Website { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Created { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Updated { get; set; }
}
```

**In my Data Project**

Abstract Folder:

```
public interface IPersonRepository
{
    IQueryable<Person> People{ get; }  
    void SavePerson(Person person);     
}
```

Concrete Folder:

**EfDb class**

```
public class EfDb : DbContext
{
    public EfDb() : base("DefaultConnection") {}

    public DbSet<Person> People{ get; set; }
}
```

**EfPersonRepository class**

```
#region Implementation of Person in IPersonRepository

public IQueryable<Person> People
{
    get { return _context.People; }
}

public void SavePerson(Persona person)
{
    if (person.PersonId == 0)
    {
        _context.People.Add(person);
    }
    else if (person.PersonId> 0)
    {
        var currentPerson = _context.People
            .Single(a => a.PersonId== person.PersonId);

        _context.Entry(currentPerson).CurrentValues.SetValues(person);
    }

    _context.SaveChanges();
}

#endregion
```

**PersonCreateViewModel** in WebUI Porject ViewModels folder

```
public class PersonCreateViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name:")]
    public string Name { get; set; }        

    [Display(Name = "Website:")]
    public string Website { get; set; }
}
```

Person Controller and Create Action:

```
public class PersonController : Controller
{
    private readonly IPersonRepository _dataSource;

    public PersonController(IPersonRepository dataSource)
    {
        _dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    // GET: /Association/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_dataSource.Associations);
    }

    // GET: /Person/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }

    // GET: /Person/Create
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
       return View();
    }

    // POST: /Person/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(PersonCreateViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                var Person = new Person
                      {
                          Name = Model.Name,
                          Website = model.Website,
                          Created = DateTime.UtcNow,
                          Updated = DateTime.UtcNow
                      };

                _dataSource.SavePerson(person);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            catch
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. ");
            }
        }

        return View(model);
    }
 }
```

Now unless I am mistaken, I expect my `PersonEditViewlModel` to look exactly like my `PersonCreateViewlModel`. But I can't figure out how to use that in my `Edit` action, provided I also have to call `SavePerson(Person person)` like I did in my `Create` action.

Note: Please no suggestions of `AutoMapper` or `ValueInjecter`.

How is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll be just like **create** except you need the record Id.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var personVm = _dataSource.People.Single(p => p.PersonId == id)
        .Select(e => new PersonEditViewModel {
                    e.PersonId = p.PersonId,
                    e.Name = p.Name,
                    e.Website = p.Website
                    ...
                });
    return View(personVm);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(PersonEditViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var person = _dataSource.People.Single(p => p.PersonId == model.PersonId);
        person.Name = model.Name;
        person.Website = model.Website;
        ...
        _dataSource.EditPerson(person);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

**Edit:**
So you don't do another query on edits

```
public void EditPerson(Person person)
{
    _context.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Modified;
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: If you look at my `SavePerson()` I made sure it does both save both new obejcts and Edited objects

Comment: @KomengeMwandila your edit would do an extra query. So either pass the PersonEditViewModel to the repository or change the person fields outside of the repository.

Comment: I made some changes to `HttpGet` as i don't have access to `.Select()` but everything seem to work now. Also, i don't need to create `EditPerson(Person person)` as `SavePerson(Person person)` is set-up to handle what your `EditPerson(Person person)` is set to do. Nonetheless, thanks for your help, much appreciated.